# Contacts statuses using Lync SDK

Tags: api, lync

Is it possible to get history of contacts statuses using Lync SDK or maybe   monitor and store history of statuses?

Answer (score 0):

You could write an application that subscribes to user presences and then write some kind of status history log from their StatusChanged events.

---

**Small startingpoint:**

Create a presence view on your Endpoint:

```
var presenceView = new RemotePresenceView(endpoint, new RemotePresenceViewSettings());
```

Subscribe to the `PresenceNotificationReceived` event:

```
presenceView.PresenceNotificationReceived += OnPresenceNotificationReceived;
```

And handle this event:

```
private void PresenceNotificationReceived(object sender, RemotePresentitiesNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var notification in e.Notifications)
    {
        // Store the notification somewhere
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do this ASAP.